# Converting to UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm calling the Google Translate API and I need to send UTF-8 as input. 
I have a piece of code to convert a string to UTF-8 but not matter what I try, when I check the encoding right after the conversion operation I get ASCII as the encoding of the string.

Here is the most popular answer I could find:

```
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);
```

The other way I tried was like this:

```
$text = utf8_encode($text);
```

As soon as I check the encoding again (on both cases) I get ASCII as the result:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($text);
```

What am I missing here? 
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: When you say you get ASCII as the encoding of the string, do you mean you post  `ápple` but only get back `pple`? A couple of other things to confirm what's the charset of the page you're posting from - check the response headers in Firebug/Inspect Element.

Comment: You guessed it right. I didn't have a charset tag in the page and by doing it I got to view the translated string correctly. However, what I thought would solve my problem proved not to be the culprit. I'm actually trying to save the translated strings to an XML file that I opened using Simplexml. In the file all Japanese characters are displayed as '&#x95EE' and many other sequences that make whatever encoding it is in...

Comment: You should be able to set the charset of the XML at the top of the document